# Jquery hover with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, navigation, hover, settimeout

I have a horizontal navigation menu and I want to show a tooltip when the user's mouse rests on the button for 1 second. Or in other words, I want there to be a delay for when the tip appears. The tooltip should disappear immediately when the user moves the mouse away. Stumbleupon's toolbar is an example of how I want this to function.

javascript:

```
$("a.btn").hover(
    function() {
        var tip = $(this).parent().children(".tip-wrapper");
        setTimeout(function{
            tip.show();
        }, 1000)
    },
    function {
        var tip = $(this).parent().children(".tip-wrapper");
        tip.hide();
    }
);
```

html:

```
<th title="">   
    <a href="#" class="btn">
        <span class="person">Firstname Lastname</span>
    </a>

    <div class="tip-wrapper">
        <div class="tip-border">
            <div class="tip">
               tool tips go here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</th>
```

I've looked at many tutorials and can't figure out why mine doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the mouse moves away before the timeout happens, you'll `hide()` it immediately, then `show()` it after the timeout runs.

Instead, you should use the [`hoverIntent` plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html), which does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

you have some syntax errors : `function {` should be `function() {` (same goes for `setTimeout(function{` => `setTimeout(function(){`);
I suggest using a variable that refers to your timeout function. That way, you can stop the appearance of the tooltip if the user does not hover the element at least one second. :

```
var timeout;
$("a.btn").hover(
    function() {
        var tip = $(this).siblings(".tip-wrapper");
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            tip.show();
        }, 1000);
    },
    function() {
        // prevent the tooltip from appearing
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        var tip = $(this).siblings(".tip-wrapper");
        tip.hide();
    }
);
```

Also, you should hide your tooltips at the beginning.  is a live working sample.

As long as you're already using jquery in your project, I suggest you take advantage of it and use it's animation function instead. This way, your code becomes :

```
$("a.btn").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).siblings('.tip-wrapper').fadeIn(1000);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).siblings('.tip-wrapper').stop().hide();// or fadeOut();
    }
);
```

p.s.:  use `.siblings()` instead of `.parent().children()`

Comment: Or to match the original intent while using stop (to avoid the timeout variable), use delay(1000).fadeIn(0): http://jsfiddle.net/Lobstrosity/wscUw/

Answer (score 0):

First, there were a few syntax errors in your script (as gion_13) pointed out.

Second, to make sure the tooltip doesn't show erroneously if the user moves the mouse away before the timeout is complete, you'll want to use a variable to store your timeout so that you can clear it in `hover`'s `handlerOut` parameter.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qA8bH/).